# changing variable type in list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to take 4 numbers as string and split them into 4 elements. and convert each of them into integer and save it in a list. What am I doing wrong here?

```
mask = "250.250.0.0"
string = mask.split(".")
toInt = [int[i] for i in string]
print(toInt)
```

error message says type object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try `int(i)`, not `int[i]`. With `()` your calling the function `int`.

Comment: `list(map(int, mask.split(".")))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham map already returning a list.

Comment: @marcadian not in python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ah interesting, I don't know it's changed, still using 2.7

Answer (score 1):

use `int(i)` instead of `int[i]`, int is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a builtin-class that provides no implementation for subscription in array-like fashion.

To convert to an integer you should use `int` like this:

```
toInt = [int(i) for i in string]
```

Comment: No, you used `int[i]`, not `int(i)`.